# Conflicting constructors in imported C# lib

Tags: f#

I can't really describe what's going on here any better than this screenshot:

[image: the problem]

The tooltip says the return type of the constructor is unit, while the "new" part says it should be Repository. Obviously a constructor should return an instance of the class itself, so why does it return unit?

Full source available at https://github.com/Kantis/GitSemVer

Comment: I found I could work around the issue by creating a C# project where I created a factory class. Check the branch called _wrapperd_ if you're curious.

Comment: I created a branch of the code as it was when the question was asked. Can someone please edit the question to point to https://github.com/Kantis/GitSemVer/tree/stackoverflow-29709578 as I lack the reputation to do so myself? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tagging constructors with `unit` is just a convention for tooltips, it doesn't affect the actual compilation.  I guess it's true that it's a bit weird/inconsistent, compared to the details shown below.

Your code is fine as-is, the squiggles on `let` are just because `CalculateVersion` does not yet contain a complete expression. If you add a return value it works fine:

```
let CalculateVersion(path:string) =
    let repo = new LibGit2Sharp.Repository(path)
    42  // return something
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I think I had another error which prevented compilation and got confused. Seems to be working now however :)